# How to connect Samsung GT-i8160 and Debian via WiFi-Direct?

Tags: wi-fi, linux, wifi-direct

The `wpa_supplicant` documentation contains information suggesting it is possible to set up a WiFi-Direct connection between a Linux box and another WiFi-Direct device. It seems it is necessary to use `wpa_cli` and issue a series of commands first of which is `p2p_find`.

However when I use `wpa_cli` this command does not seem available. I am using Debian Wheezy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that there is only `wpa_supplicant` [version 1.0](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/wpasupplicant) available in Debian Wheezy.

For support of WiFi Direct you need `wpa_supplicant` [version 1.1](https://askubuntu.com/a/304352/94697) or higher.

You can [download](http://hostap.epitest.fi/wpa_supplicant/) and compile the latest `wpa_supplicant` on your own. This way you make sure `wpa_cli` is available and WiFi Direct is supported.

Comment: Is it available in testing or experimental Debian distributions?